# Clojure - start a REPL without a project.clj

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, cider

I started using Clojure with `leiningen` (and now `boot`).

Now I sometimes want to get quickly to a Clojure{Script} CIDER REPL in Emacs to execute just a few instructions. I don't want to create a `project.clj` file for that, since I just want a throwaway REPL.

Is there a way to get a Clojure REPL, for instance in the `*scratch*` buffer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, you can execute M-x cider-jack-in anywhere you want, even with no project.clj in path. This works for me.

Comment: Wow I thought I was sure I tried that, but apparently nope.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to `C-e` from the scratch buffer though, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: you mean C-c C-e, right? just turn cider-mode, for example in a *scratch* , M-x cider-mode, and it will bootstrap all the stuff. Just checked it, works ok

Comment: Right, I get "No Clojure subprocess; see variable `inf-clojure-buffer" in the minibuffer (with clojure-mode and cider-mode enabled).

Comment: which versions of cider, leiningen and nrepl do you have? maybe you should update them? mine are: `; CIDER 0.10.0snapshot (package: 20151011.151) (Java 1.8.0_45, Clojure 1.7.0, nREPL 0.2.10)`, leiningen 2.5.3

Comment: Thanks, seems spot on. I upgraded leiningen, now I should have mentioned this message on my REPL : `; CIDER 0.10.0snapshot (package: 20151006.714) (Java 1.8.0_60, Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.6)
WARNING: CIDER requires nREPL 0.2.7 (or newer) to work properly`. But I am pretty sure also that I have more recent versions of those installed. Is there a way to specify a default version ? `./lein` maybe ?

Comment: yes, you're right, you should probably add cider-nrepl to plugins and org.clojure/tools.nrepl to dependencies in you .lein/profiles.clj , like this: {:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.0-SNAPSHOT"]] :dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.10"]]}} before starting nrepl

Comment: I will try that tomorrow,  or I may miss something. I will accept your answer if it works, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can just type `lein repl` in the friendly console / shell / terminal right next to you -- no `project.clj` required. This will start a REPL as expected, to which you can then connect from Emacs via `M-x cider-connect` (which in recent versions will handily suggest host and port to connect to). 
`M-x cider-jack-in` basically does the same thing (i.e. `lein repl`) behind the scenes.

I'm not a boot user, but according to the [boot wiki for leiningen users](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Boot-for-Leiningen-Users) it should be possible to call `boot repl -s`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `M-x cider-jack-in`, and if you don't want it to warn you that you're running `cider-jack-in` without a Clojure project, add the following to your `emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(setq cider-allow-jack-in-without-project t)
```